# How to $push , $set and $inc together in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Basically,I am using loopback with mongodb and want to push the data, set the data and increment the data together and get the final result.

For that i tried this.

```
db.invoice.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) },
        {
            $push: { payment: paymentData }
            , $set: { payment_status: true, updated_at: new Date() }
            , $inc: { total_amount_paid: paidAmt }
        }
        ,
        function (err, doc) {
            if (err) { return new Error(err); }
            else {
                if (doc.result.n>0) {
                    setTimeout(function () { }, 200);
                    console.log(" Invoice updated with Payment info.");
                    nextCall(null, { code: 200, data: doc.result });
                } else {
                    console.log("Something went wrong while payment info updation.")
                    nextCall(null, { code: 400, status: 'Something went wrong while payment info updation.' })
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Case 1 :**

Document is updating but not pushing in payment Array.

**Case 2:**

If I remove the callback function
it is pushing, setting the value and also incrementing the total amount paid.$inc

Could someone tell me where I am doing wrong if want to achieve case2 ?

Thanks

Comment: add the options object in between the update object and callback. The options should have `new: true`, this will return the updated document from the database. By default (from `v4.0`) `new` is `false`, so your `doc` in the `callback` is yet to be updated document.

Answer (score 4):

Perform `$push, $inc` operation all together

**find query:**

```
db.getCollection('noti').find({})
```

**result:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc061f05a4c0511a9252e88"),
    "count" : 8.0,
    "color" : "green",
    "icon" : "circle",
    "graph" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 6.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 8.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 8.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 9.0
        }
    ],
    "name" : "online visitor",
    "read" : false,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-10-12T08:57:20.853Z"),
    "__v" : 0.0,
    "views" : 1.0
}
```

**update query:**

```
db.getCollection('noti').findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: ObjectId("5bc061f05a4c0511a9252e88") }, 
   { $push: { 
             graph: {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
               "count" : 10.0
               }  
           },
      $inc: { count: 1 } 
   }, {new: true })
```

**result:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc061f05a4c0511a9252e88"),
    "count" : 9.0,
    "color" : "green",
    "icon" : "circle",
    "graph" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 6.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 8.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 8.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 9.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-10-24T08:55:13.331Z"),
            "count" : 10.0
        }
    ],
    "name" : "online visitor",
    "read" : false,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-10-12T08:57:20.853Z"),
    "__v" : 0.0,
    "views" : 1.0
}
```

Here count is incremented by 1 and new JSON Object is inserted into graph array.

Comment: where is $set, can i add $set: {"newColor": "$color"}